# Which is faster... XSLT macro or .NEt User Control

Tags: asp.net, xslt, user-controls, umbraco

Using Umbraco, which is quicker to load on a page...

XSLT Macro or a .NET user Control (via an Umbraco Macro).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve, and how you go about it. A well-written XSLT macro will probably perform better than a badly-written .NET macro, and vice versa. XSLT is fast and elegant when manipulating XML for the display of data, but quickly gets unwieldy when trying to deal with user interaction, for example. A rule of thumb that I use is that if you are just displaying data then use XSLT, but if you want some user interaction then use .NET.